# ffmpeg MOOV Atom on a ProRes file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

We have been asked by a client to create a ProRes QT file (.mov) but specifically asked to "***The moov atom (movie index file) should be placed at the beginning of the file.***" I have been reading around but could not find a solution for .mov files. Everybody is talking for .mp4.
The line I came with is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mov -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:6 -map 0:a:7 -movflags faststart output_ATOM.mov
```

The audio mapping and the video copying is working fine. I need to know if the ***-movflags faststart*** is actually going to do the job? I can't find a way to check the result if it actually moved the Atom.

Thanks!

Comment: .mp4 and .mov are pretty much synonymous. Moving the moov atom to the start fo the file is what faststart does, so it whould work. I don't exactly know how you'd check it, other than trying to play the movie over a slow internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for confirming stib! I actually found a way. open the file with a HEX editor and if it's correct, the moov should be at the start. Thanks!